# Servidor NO RESPONDE peticiones AJAX (Pending)

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, oracle, aspx

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]El servidor se bloquea por alguna razón, mi aplicación hace peticiones ajax a webmethods c# aspx y consultas a oracle pero se bloquea después de un rato.
Mi pregunta es existe alguna restricción de consultas o peticiones al servidor?

Uso este código para validar la existencia de un dato en una tabla en oracle. Existen horas con mucha concurrencias pero llega el momento en que el servidor ya no responde los llamados de los clientes.

Llamada con ajax:

```
    function checkDATO(funcion) {
var dato= ($("#sdato").val().length == 0) ? 0 : $("#sdato").val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/wfBoletaje.aspx/validaDATO",
    data: "{dato:'" + dato+ "'}",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    success: function (result) {
        result = result.d;

        // Existe en la Base de datos
        if (result > 0) {
            clearModal();
            $("#nisinfo").text($("#snis").val());
            $("#btnGuardarDatos").fadeIn();
            //signature.file = null;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/wfDatosCliente.aspx/ValidaDatos",
                data: "{dato:'" + $("#sdato").val() + "'}",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    result = JSON.parse(result.d);
                    if (result.length >= 1) {
                        result = result[0];
                        //clearModal();
                        secdatos = true;
                        required.push("dnacimiento");

                        $("#txtsnombre").val(result.snombre);
                        $("#txtspaterno").val(result.spaterno);
                        $("#txtsmaterno").val(result.smaterno);
                        $("#txtsmovil").val(result.smovil);
                        $("#txtsmail").val(result.smail);
                        $("#dnacimiento").val((result.dnacimiento.split("T")[0] == "1900-01-01" ? "" : result.dnacimiento.split("T")[0]));
                        $("input[name='ssexo'][value='"+result.ssexo+"']").prop('checked', true);
                        $("input[name='spersonaTipo'][value='"+result.spersonaTipo+"']").prop('checked', true);
                        $("#bfacturaElectronica").prop('checked', result.bfacturaElectronica);
                        $("#bpromociones").prop('checked', result.bpromociones);
                        $("#bboleta").prop('checked', result.bboleta);
                        $("#bsaldoSMS").prop('checked', result.bsaldoSMS);

                        if ($("#txtsnombre").val() != '') { $("#txtsnombre").prop('readonly', true) }
                        if ($("#txtspaterno").val() != '') { $("#txtspaterno").prop('readonly', true) }
                        if ($("#txtsmaterno").val() != '') { $("#txtsmaterno").prop('readonly', true) }
                        if ($("#txtsmovil").val() != '') { $("#txtsmovil").prop('readonly', true) }
                        if ($("#txtsmail").val() != '') { $("#txtsmail").prop('readonly', true) }

                        signature.file = result.badjunto;
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        funcion();
    }
});}
```

Este es el método que se bloquea por alguna razón, me he percatado que solo en horas muy activas.
WebMethod c# aspx:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static int validaDATO(int nis)
    {
        wfBoletaje bol = new wfBoletaje();
        return bol.ValidaExistente(nis);
    }

        public int ValidaExistente(int DATO)
    {
        clsOracle ora = new clsOracle();
        return ora.BackintOracle(string.Format("SELECT count(1) FROM TABLA WHERE DATO = {0}", DATO), "TABLA");
    }
```

CONSULTA EN ORACLE:

```
        public int BackintOracle(string squery, string nametable)
    {
        Conexion();
        int nvalor = 0;
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(CadenaConexion))
            {
                con.Open();
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(squery, con);
                nvalor = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {}

        return nvalor;

    }
```

Para desbloquear llamadas al servidor tengo que re-publicar para matar sesiones.

Algunas de las dudas que tengo son:
Existe un limite de llamadas al servidor?
Existe un limite de consultas simultaneas a oracle?
Hay posibilidad de que sea el pool?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido Omar, puedes poner tu código para que podamos ver como estas trabajando?? Ve a [ask] para más información

Comment: Que significa "se bloquea"? Te sugiero abrir la consola del navegador, ir a la pestaña de network o red y ver que error arroja cuando haces los ajax.

Comment: @VíctorHugoTirado Ya agregue código de back y front, aun no encuentro el origen del error.

Comment: @Emeeus No arroja errores, solo muestra las peticiones ajax en estatus pending y hasta que republico responde todas las peticiones de los clientes. Existe concurrencia de las de 100 clientes haciendo llamadas simultaneas.

Comment: No estas cerrando tu conexion, con.Close(); despues de obtener tus valores nvalor = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

Comment: Buen dia, Amigo como solucionaste éste incidente?. Me esta pasando exactamente lo mismo. Gracias