# Como mantener múltiples sesiones en Servidor IIS, Back asp.Net?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net, sesiones

Mi aplicación no mantiene **múltiples sesiones** en Servidor IIS, cuando se loguean más de 1 persona solo mantiene la última sesión y cuando algún CLIENTE ya logueado consulta la sesión, devuelve solo la del último cliente que se logueo.

Para conseguir las sesiones desde mis métodos web estáticos uso `httpcontext.current.session["Usuario"]`.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string Buscar(string suser, string spss,string suc)
    {

        try
        {
            clsUsuario _user = new clsUsuario();
             _user.BuscarUsuario(suser, spss);

            if (_user.permisoanual)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] = _user;
                HttpContext.Current.Session["Sucursal"] = suc;
                scadena = "1";
            }
            else { scadena = "0"; }

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            return "error";
        }
        return scadena;
    }
```

Para consultarla uso este Metodo Web

```
        [WebMethod]
    public static clsUsuario Usuario()
    {
        return (clsUsuario)HttpContext.Current.Session["User"];
    }
```

Llamado a método estático con ajax.

```
function InfoUsuario() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "../wfBoletaje.aspx/Usuario",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                Usuario = eval(response.d);
                $('#snombreus').html(Usuario.snombre_ + " " + Usuario.spaterno_ + " " + Usuario.smaterno_);
                console.log(Usuario);
            }
        });

    }
```

Clase Usuario

```
 public class clsUsuario
{
    #region variables
    private static Hashtable htParametros;
    private static int nusuario;
    private static string snombre;
    private static string spaterno;
    private static string smaterno;
    #endregion

    #region variables
    public int nusuario_ { get { return nusuario; } set { nusuario = value; } }
    public string snombre_ { get { return snombre; } set { snombre = value; } }
    public string spaterno_ { get { return spaterno; } set { spaterno = value; } }
    public string smaterno_ { get { return smaterno; } set { smaterno = value; } }
    public bool permisoanual { get; set; }
    public bool permisocancel { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region variables
    public clsUsuario()
    {
        nusuario = 0;
        snombre = "";
        spaterno = "";
        smaterno = "";
    }

    public void BuscarUsuario(string susuario, string spassword)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        htParametros = new Hashtable();
        htParametros.Add("s@susuario", susuario);
        htParametros.Add("s@spassword", spassword);
        htParametros.Add("s@spassword2", encriptarContraseña(spassword));
        dt = DataBase.clsMSSQL.SP_DataTable2("[bdSistemaIntegral].[Tiketto].[SP_Logeo_Tiketto]", htParametros);

        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
                nusuario_ = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["nusuario"].ToString());
                snombre_ = dt.Rows[0]["snombre"].ToString();
                spaterno_ = dt.Rows[0]["spaterno"].ToString();
                smaterno_ = dt.Rows[0]["smaterno"].ToString();["bcancel"].ToString());
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

No se que cambio, ya que uso este mismo codigo para varios proyectos pero solo este presenta esta problemática.

Puede ser configuración del web.config
Configuración del servidor

Comment: Hola, indica por favor un ejemplo en código de los métodos estáticos que usas. Sobre todo donde creas las variables de sesión.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta Te comparto mi WebMethod con el que creo la variable de session.

Comment: Tienes algún ejemplo en código donde llamas al método estático `Usuario()` ?. Por que ahí es donde tienes el error. E indica también la clase `clsUsuario `

Comment: @RafaelAcosta Ya agregue todo mi código.
Te comento que ya uso este código en otras aplicaciones pero solo esta presenta este problema.

Comment: Que version de ASP.NET estas usando?  no es recomendable que IIS maneje la sesion por cuestiones de limpieza de memoria no controlada por IIS  algunas veces se puede perder la informacion de seson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución y el origen del problema.

```
public class clsUsuario {
#region variables
private static Hashtable htParametros;
private static int nusuario;
private static string snombre;
private static string spaterno;
private static string smaterno;
#endregion
}
```

Las variables estáticas no permitían que existiera mas de una sesión activa, de alguna forma al inicializar una nueva variable de tipo clsUsuario sobre escribía la variable de sesión por su propiedad estática, por lo que se quito esa propiedad y se resolvió.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Entonces revisa tus otras aplicaciones porque si dices que lo usas en varias tambien debes corregirlas.

Comment: @MiguelZarate Si, ya revisé. Esta es la única que tiene estas características (variables estáticas) con la finalizad de ahorrar recursos, ya que tengo otra problemática aun sin resolver.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/302143/servidor-no-responde-peticiones-ajax-pending